# Wierd result in formatting float value to string using String.format

Tags: java, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-conversion

I'm kinda recent to Java. 
I understand in general the issues around floating point precision and conversion but not sure why am seeing such a ridiculous result in Java...
I did this...

```
String str1 = String.format("%.02f", 0.001921921f);
String str2 = String.format("%.02f", 9.0921921f);
String str3 = String.format("%.02f", 91.21921f);
String str4 = String.format("%.02f", 911212.09f); // WIERD: Prints 911212.06 !!!
String str5 = String.format("%.02f", 1212f);
```

And saw these values in the strings in debug mode (Eclipse debugger / Eclipse Platform 4.2.1 / Java SE 6 (Mac Mavericks OSX default))...

```
str1 = "0.00"
str2 = "9.09"
str3 = "91.22"
str4 = "911212.06"   ===> What the heck ?? Should be "911212.09" or some rounding of that?
str5 = "1212.00"
```

I don't understand this at all.

Lemme also explain what I'm ultimately trying to do...

I have a bunch of input float values to varying decimal precision, converted from strings like "9.34", "99.131", etc). 

I want to truncate all decimal places beyond the second and get an INT with all the digits (no decimal places, no floor / ceiling / rounding etc) ie. 19.2341 will become 1923, 19.2359 will also be 1923 and not 1924. 

 Now I tried doing things like

```
int ival = (int)(float_val * 100.0);
```

But that has precision/accuracy issues. Eg. if float_val contained 17.3f then ival becomes 1729.

I thought using formatted strings might help, but that also does rounding and while trying it I  also saw the wierd case above.

 Any idea what I'm doing wrong ? 

 For now, for my situation I'll just manipulate the original string values to truncate the decimal places and remove the decimal point and then convert to int.

Comment: try newer jdk, if its diff then you hit a bug

Comment: if you want precision, use BigDecimal.

Comment: also, casting a float to an int does _not_ do rounding, it does truncation.

Comment: i didn't downvote anything.  you should be careful about the assumptions you make before casting aspersions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `float` has 23 bits of precision.  To represent 911212.09, within a range of + or - 0.005, requires 27 bits (I could be off by one).  Therefore it should not be surprising that the result is off.

If you use `double` (by removing the `f` from the numeric literal), you'll get 52 bits of precision, so the error would small enough that it wouldn't affect the result when you format to two decimal places.

But using `BigDecimal` is better.

This is not a Java or JDK issue, by the way.  It will occur in any language where you're trying to use a 32-bit IEEE 754 float type.  Please read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is simply that the intern representation of a `float` (as described in the **IEEE 754** format) is not precise enough to handle `911212.09f` as you expected.

It is actually only stored on a 32-bits value, distributed as follows:

- **1** bit for the **sign**
- **8** bits for the exponent and only...
- **23** bits for the *mantissa*.

This leaves us with only **23** bits of precision and the closest we can represent as a `float` to `911212.09` is actually `911212.0625`.

You can understand more in depth how this all works by reading [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) or play around with this online converter: [IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

[image]

---

As @ajb mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25597894), simply using the `double` type would get you sorted on this case ;)

i.e.:

```
//                                        removed 'f' here
//                                                v
System.out.println(String.format("%.02f", 911212.09));
```

... will output:

```
911212.09
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clear. Using double works for this case